# sap.ui.core.Fragment.load returns undefined

Tags: fragment, sapui5

There are two FLP tiles in my app. One can access to `sap.ui.core.Fragment.load`, but the other cannot.

- The working one:

[image]

- The not working one:

[image]

and `byId` returns a **lazy stub** ?
[image]

They both load UI5 by

```
<script
  id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize_plus"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ushell, sap.collaboration"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-frameOptions='allow'
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "monitor": "./",
    "common": "./../../../common"
  }'>
</script>
```

The not working one does not have `Fragment.js` in the SAPUI5 resource, but I can access to [Fragment-dbg.js](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/core/Fragment-dbg.js?eval)

[image]

I have also compared `manifest.json`, there is no difference. Is there any other clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that after `sap.ui.xmlfragment()`, `Fragment.load()` exists.
So add it to `sap.ui.define` or `.require`, then it works.

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], function(Fragment){
  Fragment.load({
    name: "namespace.myFragment",
    controller: this
  }).then(function(oFragment) {
    // ...
  }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Thanks to @Boghyon Hoffmann:

> the factory functions inside the `sap.ui.*` namespace have also been refactored. UI5 now provide fully asynchronous APIs on top.
>   The old APIs are of course still available for compatibility reasons, but are also deprecated.
>   [Modularization of the SAPUI5 Core](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/19/ui5ers-buzz-38-modularization-of-the-sapui5-core/)

New API must use modular way, which means use `sap.ui.require` / `sap.ui.define`.

---

Documentation: [Legacy Factories Replacement](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/491bd9c70b9f4c4d913c8c7b4a970833)

Comment: It's always a good practice (I'd say mandatory) to include the required modules in the dependency definition, as you did, which will also avoid potential stubs and sync XHRs: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/19/ui5ers-buzz-38-modularization-of-the-sapui5-core/